# Call to NSManagedObjectContext save doesn't return in certain situations

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am relatively new to Core Data and am looking for some advice.
My project: I have a few object here: 
 - SMCoreData which is largely the auto generated code around a CoreData
   project 
 - SMUploader which indexes assets in ALAssetLibrary, writes the results to SMCoreData, and has a queue mechanism to upload photos. 
 - SMUploaderViewController a UICollectionView and a few switches which show the progress of the queue.

These classes work great for the most part. When a user launches the app, their Camera Roll is indexed and uploading begins. It will successfully upload 1000's of photos.

The problem comes later when more is added to the upload queue. I'm observing changes to the ALAssetLibrary (say someone saves a photo using Safari). My app will receive the notification, queue the image, and try to upload it when the user flips the switch (same as earlier).

This is where I am running into a quirk. I first grab the next object from core data, acuire the asset from a URL (core data object), then copy the file to my sandbox. I then go to update CoreData with the filesize and temporaryFilePath. However the call to [context save] never returns (however it has already worked great 1000s of times before). The processor is at 0% and it just sits there not returning. Sounds like a queue problem at first, however I am using background queues:

MYCoreData is mainly the boilerplate code from a CoreData project. I moved it to a class to encapsulate it. I did change how the managedObjectContext is created though:

```
_managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
```

MYUploader has two queues. One for indexing the asset library, and one for processing the upload queue.

MYUploaderViewController has a registers a few calllback blocks with MYUploader so that UI updates can be rendered. These calls are always done from the main queue withing MYUploader.

A little code:

```
-(void)uploadAsset:(SMUploadAsset*)uploadAsset completion:(SMUploaderBoolBlock)completion{
        // 1.) Dump asset to a temporary file to operate with
        // 1a) Update core data with temporaryFile, size, and md5
        // 2.) Create asset on our server
        // 2a) Update core data with s3URL
        // 3.) Upload file to s3RUL
        // 4.) Tell our server that the upload has completed
        // 5.) Update core data with uploaded and uploadedDate
        // 6.) Delete temporary file
        // 7.) Remove the uploadAsset from the queue

        NSLog(@"%s", __func__);
        if(uploadAsset.image){
            NSLog(@"........................................................... Uploading Image ................................................ ");
            uploadAsset.uploadQueueState = SMUploadAssetQueueStateInProgress;
            // 1.) Dump asset to a temporary file to operate with
            NSLog(@"Upload step 1. ");
            NSURL *assetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", uploadAsset.image.uri]];
            NSLog(@"--- UPLOAD 1.) Dumping file");
            [SMUploaderImageRipper bytesFromObject:assetURL completion:^(SMUploadProperties *uploadProperties) {
                if(uploadProperties == nil){
                    NSLog(@"Upload step 1 FAILED");
                    uploadAsset.uploadQueueState = SMUploadAssetQueueStateFailed;
                    NSLog(@"****** UPLOAD ERROR: Failed to dump asset to temporary file");
                    completion(NO);
                    return;
                }
                NSLog(@"Upload step 1 complete");

                // 1a) Update core data with temporaryFile, size, and md5
                NSLog(@"Upload step 1a. Updating core data with temp file, size, and md5");
                [self updateUploadAsset:uploadAsset uploadProperties:uploadProperties completion:^(BOOL success) {
                    if(success == NO){
                        NSLog(@"Upload step 1a FAILED");
                        uploadAsset.uploadQueueState = SMUploadAssetQueueStateFailed;
                        NSLog(@"****** UPLOAD ERROR: Failed to add temporaryFile, size, and md5 to CoreData");
                        completion(NO);
                        return;
                    }
                    NSLog(@"Upload step 1a complete");
    ....
```

And then the method that updates CoreData object:

```
-(void)updateUploadAsset:(SMUploadAsset*)uploadAsset
        uploadProperties:(SMUploadProperties*)uploadProperties
              completion:(SMUploaderBoolBlock)completion{

        SMCoreData *coreData = [SMCoreData sharedInstance];
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [coreData managedObjectContext];
        uploadAsset.md5 = uploadProperties.hash;
        uploadAsset.temporaryFile = uploadProperties.temporaryFile;
        uploadAsset.size = uploadProperties.size;
        NSError *cdError;
        // THIS CALL NEVER RETURNS
        if (![context save:&cdError]) {
            NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [cdError localizedDescription]);
            completion(NO);
        }
        completion(YES);
}
```

I am happy to post more code or answer questions as I am quite stuck.

UPDATE: It seems to me that it's the ALAssetLibarary observer that's causing this problem somehow. Here is what I am doing for the notification. I've tried using the main queue as well as a different background queue I have, but always this is what gets CoreData into the funky state. If I comment this out, then run the app as described above (go to safari, save an image, return) but instead of receiving this notification, I just press a button which calls this same code (enqueueCameraRollWithCompletion), everthing works great.

What could be the solution here? I would really like to keep this feature in.

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification
                                                  object:nil
                                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                                              usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
                                                  dispatch_async(self.processingQueue, ^{
                                                      [self enqueueCameraRollWithCompletion:^(BOOL success) {
                                                      }];
                                                  });
                                              }];

EDIT: Requested code update using performBlockAndWait

```
-(void)updateUploadAsset:(SMUploadAsset*)uploadAsset
        uploadProperties:(SMUploadProperties*)uploadProperties
              completion:(SMUploaderBoolBlock)completion{

    SMCoreData *coreData = [SMCoreData sharedInstance];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [coreData managedObjectContext];

    [context performBlockAndWait:^{
        uploadAsset.md5 = uploadProperties.hash;
        uploadAsset.temporaryFile = uploadProperties.temporaryFile;
        uploadAsset.size = uploadProperties.size;

        if ([coreData saveContext]){
            completion(YES);
        }
        else{
            completion(NO);
        }

    }];
}
```

Comment: You seem to use a "private queue" context without `performBlock:` or `performBlockAndWait:` calls

Comment: I've ready up on performBlock and it's wait derivative. I've implemented these blocks so that my code uses them to write to the DB and I'm still seeing the issue. Any other ideas on this?

Comment: Could you edit your code to reflect the changes ...

Comment: Certainly. I've added to the end vs overwriting the original to retain readability.

Comment: You must also add this pattern in your `-(void)uploadAsset:(SMUploadAsset*)uploadAsset completion:(SMUploaderBoolBlock)completion` method (around the parts using `uploadAsset`) also, since you already have a reference to `uploadAsset` I believe that you must do that in another point at your code. rethink the way you execute your upload flow, or use a confined-context instead of a private-queue one.